# What is the best way to remove items above a diagonal in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, diagonal

I have a data.frame with correlations below the diagonal and p-values above the diagonal. I was trying to figure out if there's an easy way to remove the p-values above the diagonal - just leaving the cell blank. I'm guessing this would be some kind of loop function that counts the number of columns then goes row by row removing values? But I'm a bit new to R and having trouble figuring it out. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing there were downvotes because you didn't provide a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way

```
> x <- data.frame(matrix(1:25, nrow=5))
> x[upper.tri(x)] <- NA
> x
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1 NA NA NA NA
2  2  7 NA NA NA
3  3  8 13 NA NA
4  4  9 14 19 NA
5  5 10 15 20 25
```

Though, from your description, I'd have thought that a matrix would be a more appropriate data structure (the same code applies)